# Finding the pair number of a sum in java

Tags: java, sum

```
public class Test{                                      
  public static void pair(int array[], int data){                                       
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++){                                     
            for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++){                                     
                if (array[i] + array[j] == data){                                       
                    System.out.println("Pair: " + i + " and " + j);                                     
                    return;                                     
                }                                       
            }                                       
        }                                       
        System.out.println("Pair not found");                                       
    }                                       
}                                       

public class Main                                       
{                                       
  public static void main(String[] args)                                        
  {                                     
    int[] num = {1,6,8,12,19};                                      
    Test.pair(num,20);                                                                          
  }                                     
}
```

I am trying to create a pair of given sum for example, it would output from the middle numbers to outer numbers e.g. 8,12 and 1,19. But my current output is just 0 and 4

Answer (score 0):

You are only outputting your loop variables `i` & `j`. You need to access the array at those positions:

```
System.out.println("Pair: " + array[i] + " and " + array[j]);
```

This will only print out 1 matching pair because of the `return`. If you need more, you'll need to remove that & use a variable to control whether or not the message gets printed.